# Route HTTP request to HTTPS in AWS Load Balancer

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

We have 2 EC2 instances with Nginx and Unicorn running Rails. We started the Load Balancing option in EC2. Next we bought a SSL certificate and got it working on the Load Balancer. Hence, now we have url working for https://app.mydomain.com. We removed HTTP from the Load Balancer's listeners. Now, we need to somehow route http://app.mydomain.com of any incoming request to https://app.mydomain.com every time. Any suggestions on how we can achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You bought an SSL *certificate.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding SSL communication between ELB EC2 on AWS and forcing only HTTPS comunication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508312/adding-ssl-communication-between-elb-ec2-on-aws-and-forcing-only-https-comunicat)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same case and I solve it by:

You need to keep the load balance listen into port 80 and into your ec2 instace which running as nodes you can configure it to redirect any http request to https.

in my case I use this lines in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule !/status https://app.mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

this was my case while /status while the load balance checker to check the instance helath.

Answer (score 0):

ELB sets `X-Forwarded-Proto` header, you can use it to detect if original request was to HTTP and redirect to HTTPS then.

Take a look at [ELB docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/TerminologyandKeyConcepts.html#x-forwarded-headers).

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure in your apache or nginx file. Use this link for detail help. https://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom

Comment: The SSL is not configured at each instance level but at the Load Balancer level. Hence, the HTTP request does not each NGINX and fails at Load Balancer itself.